# Using RSpec, how can I test that a method is called with instance of a class but with specific values on specific attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I want to write a test like the following:

```
account = Account.find(1)
@controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(:create, instance_of(User, :account_id => account.id))
```

(exact example on testing the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem on a controller of mine)

I know that the part `:account_id => account.id` is invalid.

My question goes here:

How can I call the `instance_of` but at the same time test the attributes of the instance to have specific values?

I hope that this is clear. Otherwise, let me know, how can I make it more clear.

Thanks in advance

Panayotis

Comment: What are you trying to test? That the controller loads the proper instance? If then something like :

Account.should_receive(:find).returns(account))
@controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(account)

If this is the desired let me know an put it as a formal reply :D

Comment: Ahhhh. yes. I think this is the correct answer. (Though I believe that I should be checking on that later on). But, yes, please, post that as your official answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a block for more control on the expected arguments, more info: 
[Argument matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-7/docs/argument-matchers)

Comment: The above link is broken as of 11/20/2014. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-7/docs/argument-matchers is a working link.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to test? That the controller loads the proper instance and the passes the proper instance to `:authorize!`? If yes, then something like :

```
Account.should_receive(:find).returns(account))
@controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(account)
```

would do the job

Comment: Sorry, @nikos-d This is not the correct answer. My comment on your comment was not after careful thought. I have to check whether the instance is of type User with specific argument value on `account_id` attribute, not whether it is a specific instance of Account.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the accepted answer, it is possible to use [argument matchers](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-7/docs/argument-matchers) to do the following:

```
expect(controller).to receive(:authorize!).with do |symbol, received_user|
  expect(symbol).to eq :create
  expect(received_user).to be_a User
  expect(received_user.account).to eq account
end
```